# Connect four game, if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

Here is code for my connect four game for exam. There are seven columns, if a number above 7 is entered it should say "Move not allowed", but if 0 is entered it should save the game.

When I enter 0 it says "Move not allowed". There is a code to save the game when 0 is entered but it says "Move not allowed" and doesn't go there. Can someone help?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct gameState{
    int id;
    char board[6][7];
    int numberOfMoves;
    char player1Name[20];
    char player2Name[20];

}GameState;

void ShowMenu() {
    printf("\n\n\n1. New Game \n");
    printf("2. Load Game \n");
    printf("3. Exit \n\n");
    printf("Choose: ");
}

void ReadPlayerNames(char player1Name[20], char player2Name[20]) {

    printf("\nName of first player:");
    scanf("%s", player1Name);

    printf("\nName of second player:");
    scanf("%s", player2Name);
}

void PrintBoard(char board[6][7])
{
    char header[] = "  1   2   3   4   5   6   7  ";
    char border[] = "|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|";
    printf("%s\n", header);
    printf("%s\n", border);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            printf("| %c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
        printf("%s\n", border);
    }
}

void ClearBoard(char board[6][7]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

// 1 - X wins, 2 - O wins, 0 - still playing
int CheckDiagonals(char board[6][7], int i, int j, int goUpRight){
    int connectedO = 0;
    int connectedX = 0;

    while(i >= 0){
        if (board[i][j] != ' '){
            if (board[i][j] == 'X'){
                connectedX++;
                connectedO = 0;

                if (connectedX == 4){
                    if (goUpRight = 0){
                        board[i][j] = 'Y';            //checking if x won, putting Y on places of x
                        board[i + 1][j + 1] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 2][j + 2] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 3][j + 3] = 'Y';
                    } else {
                        board[i][j] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 1][j - 1] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 2][j - 2] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 3][j - 3] = 'Y';
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                connectedO++;
                connectedX = 0;

                if (connectedO == 4){
                    if (goUpRight = 0){
                        board[i][j] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 1][j + 1] = 'Y';   //checking if o won, putting Y on places of o
                        board[i + 2][j + 2] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 3][j + 3] = 'Y';
                    } else {
                        board[i][j] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 1][j - 1] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 2][j - 2] = 'Y';
                        board[i + 3][j - 3] = 'Y';
                    }
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            connectedO = 0;
            connectedX = 0;
        }

        i--;
        if (goUpRight == 1){
            j++;
        }else{
            j--;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// 1 - X wins, 2 - O wins, 0 - still playing
int CheckRowsOrCols(char board[6][7], int rows){
    int connectedO = 0;
    int connectedX = 0;

    int brI = 6;
    int brJ = 7;

    if (rows == 0){
        brI = 7;
        brJ = 6;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < brI; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < brJ; j++) {
            int pI = i, pJ = j;

            if (rows == 0){
                pI = j;
                pJ = i;
            }

            if (board[pI][pJ] != ' '){
                if (board[pI][pJ] == 'X'){
                    connectedX++;
                    connectedO = 0;

                    if (connectedX == 4){
                        if (rows == 0){
                            board[pI][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 1][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 2][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 3][pJ] = 'Y';
                        } else {
                            board[pI][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 1] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 2] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 3] = 'Y';
                        }
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    connectedO++;
                    connectedX = 0;

                    if (connectedO == 4){
                        if (rows == 0){
                            board[pI][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 1][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 2][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI - 3][pJ] = 'Y';
                        } else {
                            board[pI][pJ] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 1] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 2] = 'Y';
                            board[pI][pJ - 3] = 'Y';
                        }
                        return 2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                connectedO = 0;
                connectedX = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// 1 - X wins, 2 - O wins, 0 - still playing
int CheckForWinner(char board[6][7]) {
    int rezultat = CheckRowsOrCols(board, 1);
    if (rezultat != 0){
        return rezultat;
    }

    rezultat = CheckRowsOrCols(board, 0);
    if (rezultat != 0){
        return rezultat;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        rezultat = CheckDiagonals(board, i, 0, 1);
        if (rezultat != 0){
            return rezultat;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        rezultat = CheckDiagonals(board, 5, j, 1);
        if (rezultat != 0){
            return rezultat;
        }

        rezultat = CheckDiagonals(board, 5, j, 0);
        if (rezultat != 0){
            return rezultat;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        rezultat = CheckDiagonals(board, i, 6, 0);
        if (rezultat != 0){
            return rezultat;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void SaveGame(char board[6][7], int movesPlayed, char player1Name[20], char player2Name[20]){
    printf("\n\n\nEnter ID for your game: ");
    int id;
    scanf("%d", &id);

    GameState state;
    state.id = id;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            state.board[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
    }

    state.numberOfMoves = movesPlayed;
    strcpy(state.player1Name, player1Name);
    strcpy(state.player2Name, player2Name);

    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen("SavedGames.dat", "ab");
    if (filePointer == NULL){
        printf("\nGames not found!");
        return;
    }

    fwrite(&state, sizeof(state), 1, filePointer);
    fclose(filePointer);
    printf("\nGame with ID:%d saved!", id);
}

int MakeMove(char board[6][7], int movesPlayed, char player1Name[20], char player2Name[20]) {
    char sign = 'X';
    if (movesPlayed % 2 == 1){
        sign = 'O';
    }

    int column;
    while (1){
        printf("\nChoose the column player %c(0 for save and exit): ", sign);
        column;
        scanf("%d", &column);

        if (column >= 0 && column <= 7 && board[0][column-1] == ' '){
            break;
        }

        printf("\nMove not allowed!\n");
    }

    if (column != 0){
        for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (board[i][column-1] == ' ') {
                board[i][column-1] = sign;
                printf("\n\n\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }else {
        SaveGame(board, movesPlayed, player1Name, player2Name);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void PlayGame(char board[6][7], char player1Name[20], char player2Name[20], int movesPlayed){
    while (1){
        PrintBoard(board);

        if (MakeMove(board, movesPlayed, player1Name, player2Name) == 1){
            break;
        }
        movesPlayed++;

        int result = CheckForWinner(board);
        if (result != 0){
            PrintBoard(board);

            if (result == 1){
                printf("\nX wins\n\n\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nO wins\n\n\n");
            }

            break;
        }
        if (movesPlayed == 42){
            PrintBoard(board);

            printf("\nTie!\n\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void ListAllSavedGames(){
    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen("SavedGames.dat", "rb");
    if (filePointer == NULL){
        printf("\nGames not played yet!");
        return;
    }

    GameState state;

    while(fread(&state, sizeof(state), 1, filePointer) == 1){
        printf("\n%d, X: %s, O: %s, %d", state.id, state.player1Name, state.player2Name, (42 - state.numberOfMoves));
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
}

void ListAllPlayerGames(){
    char playerName[20];
    printf("\nName of player: ");
    scanf("%s", playerName);

    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen("SavedGames.dat", "rb");
    if (filePointer == NULL){
        printf("\nGames not played yet!");
        return;
    }

    GameState state;

    while(fread(&state, sizeof(state), 1, filePointer) == 1){
        if (strcmp(playerName, state.player1Name) == 0 || strcmp(playerName, state.player2Name) == 0){
            printf("\n%d, X: %s, O: %s, %d", state.id, state.player1Name, state.player2Name, (42 - state.numberOfMoves));

        }
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
}

int ShowTheBoard(){
    int ID;
    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &ID);

    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen("SavedGames.dat", "rb");
    if (filePointer == NULL){
        printf("\nGames not played yet!");
        return;
    }

    int IDfound = 0;
    GameState state;

    while(fread(&state, sizeof(state), 1, filePointer) == 1){
        if (ID == state.id){
            IDfound = 1;
            printf("\nX: %s, O: %s", state.player1Name, state.player2Name);
            PrintBoard(state.board);
        }
    }

    fclose(filePointer);

    if (IDfound == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int LoadAGame(){
    int ID;
    printf("\nEnter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &ID);

    FILE *filePointer;

    filePointer = fopen("SavedGames.dat", "rb");
    if (filePointer == NULL){
        printf("\nGames not played yet!");
        return;
    }

    int IDfound = 0;
    GameState state;

    while(fread(&state, sizeof(state), 1, filePointer) == 1){
        if (ID == state.id){
            IDfound = 1;
            PlayGame(state.board, state.player1Name, state.player2Name, state.numberOfMoves);
        }
    }

    fclose(filePointer);

    if (IDfound == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void ShowLoadMenu(){
    int returnToMainMenu = 0;
    while (returnToMainMenu == 0){
        printf("\n\n\n1. List all saved games\n");
        printf("2. List all saved games for a particular player\n");
        printf("3. Show the board of one of the saved games\n");
        printf("4. Load a game\n");
        printf("5. Return to main menu\n");
        printf("Choose: ");

        int choice;
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            ListAllSavedGames();
            break;
        case 2:
            ListAllPlayerGames();
            break;
        case 3:
            while (ShowTheBoard() == 1){
                printf("ID not valid!");
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            while (LoadAGame() == 1){
                printf("ID not valid!");
            }
            returnToMainMenu = 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            returnToMainMenu = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong choice, try again!");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int endOfProgram = 0;

    while (endOfProgram == 0){
        char board[6][7];
        char player1Name[20];
        char player2Name[20];
        int movesPlayed = 0;

        ShowMenu();

        int choice;
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
        case 1:
            ClearBoard(board);
            ReadPlayerNames(player1Name, player2Name);

            PlayGame(board, player1Name, player2Name, movesPlayed);
            break;
        case 2:
            ShowLoadMenu();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Goodbye!");
            endOfProgram = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong choice, try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Probably it is because `board[0][column-1] == ' '` evaluates to false if `column == 0`.
The last condition should only be checked if `column >= 1`. Note that accessing an array with negative indexes often leads to crashes

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: [Too much code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Comment: I got it to work, thank you Ronald so much! Changed if statement to:        if(column >= 1 && column <= 7 && board[0][column-1] == ' '){

           break;
        }
        else if(column == 0){
            SaveGame(board, movesPlayed, player1Name, player2Name);
            return 1;
        }
            printf("\nMove not allowed!\n");
    }

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Culprit is likely to be inside `MakeMove`:

```
if (column >= 0 && column <= 7 && board[0][column-1] == ' ') {
    break;
}
```

if you pass `0` as column, the first 2 tests will indeed succeed (both `0 >= 0` and `0 <= 7` are true). But third one tries to use `board[0][-1]`. `-1` is not a valid index and you are invoking UB.

If `column` is 0, you should not test anything else, so your test should be:

```
if (column == 0 || (column > 0 && column <= 7
                    && board[0][column-1] == ' ')) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Will this allow the player to repeatedly make moves on column 0 even when it's full?

Comment: @byxor: there is no column 0 here. First column has number 1 (according to  `PringBoard` source). The convention is that 0 means *end of game*.